# Jupypter Notebook in VS Code won't compile Latex Code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I'm new to programming and this forum. My problem is that latex code in markdown cells in a Jupypter notebook opened in vs code won't compile properly. I know that there are several threads already here in this forum and in the internet, but nothing worked so far.

I got to the point where I completely reinstalled my macbook.

So I run the latest VS Code Version on High Sierra, Python is installed via condo and my vs code extensions are python from microsoft and the Jupypter extension.

When VS code is newly installed first everything works but the second time the layout of the Jupyter notebooks changes and latex code won't compile any more.

So The first picture is how it looks on my computer, the second is how it should look. I also recognize, the look of the notebook is slightly different as kernel and host information are (in the second photo) visualized on top of the notebook - below the tabs there is a bar that show the information and also the play sign and so on to run cells.

The weird thing is, that in the beginning, first time after complete installation, on my computer it looked like it should, second time (and every time after that) it changed and it's not working any more without me changing anything.

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

[first pic - my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iokz.png)

[second pic - how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io9hI.png)